# Ideal of Clifford algebra

Tags: ideals, riemannian-geometry, tensors, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

The left ideal of an algebra $A$ is a subspace $I$ of $A$ such that $ax\in I ~~\forall a\in A, x\in I$.   A two-sided ideal is a subset of $A$ that is both a left and right ideal.

In Definition 2.4.1, $I=\{v\otimes v+||v||^2:v\in V\}$, but for $-1\in \mathbb R$ , $-v\otimes v-||v||^2$ can be presented by the form $v\otimes v+||v||^2$,  what is wrong ?

> [image]

Comment: This is an ideal of the *tensor algebra* unless you consider it the zero ideal of the Clifford algebra, of course. You can generate a two-sided ideal containing any prescribed subset of an algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal $I$ is generated by $\{v\otimes v+||v||^2:v\in V\}$, but $I \neq \{v\otimes v+||v||^2:v\in V\}$. The ideal is much larger $I=\{T_1 \otimes (v\otimes v+||v||^2) \otimes T_2:v\in V, T_1, T_2 \in T(V)\}$, here $T(V)$ is the tensor algebra.

In particular it works for $T_2=-1$ or $T_1=-1$, here $T_{1,2}$ is a degree $0$ tensor:
$$
(-1) \otimes (v\otimes v+||v||^2)=(v\otimes v+||v||^2)\otimes (-1)=-v\otimes v-||v||^2 \in I.
$$ 
And in the same way for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
x\otimes (v\otimes v+||v||^2)=(v\otimes v+||v||^2)\otimes x=x(v\otimes v+||v||^2) \in I.
$$

Comment: I still can't see $\forall T\in I, x\in \mathbb R\Rightarrow Tx\in I$.

Comment: Do you know some book about Clifford algebra (and Spin structure ) which is suitable for Riemannian geometric students ?

Comment: I think there is at least a dozen of books on this topic. The canonical reference book is  H. Blaine Lawson, Marie-Louise Michelsohn Spin Geometry. I like chapter 3 of Berline-Getzler-Vergne Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators.